# How can I Install Presto on HDInsight?

Tags: azure, presto, azure-hdinsight

I am new to the HDInsight of Azure.
I am trying to install presto on the HDInsight cluster.

As a test, I want to run TPC-H Query over. Here are what I did so far.

1. I loaded TPC-H tables on Hive
2. I am able to run a query over hive cli.
3. I am able to run `show tables` query on presto cli.
4. I am not able to run queries such as `select count(*) from region;` with `Query 20200605_074052_00011_6etih failed: cannot create caching file system` error message.

When I submit `show tables` query on presto cli, I got messages below.

`Query 20200605_074050_00010_6etih, FINISHED, 5 nodes
Splits: 70 total, 70 done (100.00%)
0:00 [8 rows, 326B] [27 rows/s, 1.08KB/s]`

I barely touched hadoop settings such as hdfs-site.xml or, core-site.xml and presto's configuration is nothing but settings about memories.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Starburst Presto from HDInsights marketplace.
Read more: https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/azure-hdinsight-and-starburst-brings-presto-to-microsoft-azure-customers/

However, Starburst does not provide an updated version of this solution, recommending Kuberneters-based (e.g. using Azure AKS) solution instead. See https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/installation/azure.html

Disclaimer: I am from Starburst.